# graphql: Unexpected invocation at runtime. Either the Babel transform was not set up, or it failed to identify this call site

Tags: reactjs, graphql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84bm0.png)
below is the link that the actual error am facing 
i m facing this problem in simple react-js relay modern
i have tried these all kind of steps about the babel-loader
 like

package.json
in package.json i have tried this after find some solutions but i didn't fix it

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-relay": "^4.0.0",
    "graphql": "^14.3.1",
    "relay-compiler": "^4.0.0"
  },
```

i am start with graphql but facing this problem i have already create schema and successfully run "yarn run relay"
but still this error

```
import React from 'react';
import  env  from './environment';
import { graphql, QueryRenderer } from 'react-relay';

const App = () => (
  <QueryRenderer
    environment={env}
    query={graphql`
      query AppQuery{
        allPersons {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    `}
    variables={{}}
    render={({error, props}) => {
      if (error) {
        return <div>Error!</div>;
      }if(!props){
        return <div>Loading...</div>;
      }
      return <div>user</div>;
    }}
  />
);
export default App;
```

Comment: you're probably looking for `graphql-tag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this command

```
npm eject
```

and open your package.json file
add this babel settings

```
"babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      [
        "relay"
      ]
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of places you can `import graphql from`. I see above you are importing from react-relay.

I found that if I changed from

```js
import { graphql, QueryRenderer } from "react-relay";
```

to

```
import { QueryRenderer } from "react-relay";
import graphql from 'babel-plugin-relay/macro';
```

it fixed my problem. I think this is because the presets determined by the `"babel":` key in the package.json apply to the babel plugin's graphql and not react-relay's graphql.

Comment: For `create-react-app` users, this is recommended method. [Create React App - Adding relay](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-relay/

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and tried everything and it did not help, until I realized I was updating .babelrc but changes were not being actually used by babel.

This was because I use babel-loader with webpack and specified presets/plugins directly in the webpack config.

Updating the webpack config to add the relay plugin worked, when nothing else did.